# Nginx sub_filter rewrites?

Tags: nginx

I am trying to rewrite body links of a proxied page using something like this:

```
    sub_filter http://proxied.page.come http://local.page.com;
    sub_filter_once off;
```

Is this the way to go at all ?
What is the difference between the [sub_filter module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) and the [substitutions_filter](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/substitutions/)

Also can variable be used in the sub_filter delcaration ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, you should ask backend to write correct links.  While it is possible to fix some simple cases using sub filter, it is not something generally possible (e.g. if returned data isn't text but e.g. flash code).

You can use variables in a replacement string in sub_filter (but not in string to match in original response), it's explicitly [documented](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html#sub_filter):

> A replacement string can contain variables.

As for subs filter - it's a 3rd party module which is expected to be more powerful, though may contain more bugs. As long as standard sub filter is enough for you - you probably don't want to use 3rd party subs filter.

Answer (score 14):

This is a perfectly valid way to rewrite links on a proxied page.
"The `ngx_http_sub_module` module is a filter that modifies a response by replacing *one specified string* by another" (single substitution)

The third party `nginx_substitutions_filter` is a filter module which can do *both regular expression and fixed string substitutions* on response bodies

So the third party module can be used to substitute multiple strings, using regex and variables. e.g.:

```
subs_filter_types text/css text/xml;
subs_filter http(s)?://(www.)?proxied.page.com/     http$1://$http_host/ r;
subs_filter http(s)?://(www.)?proxied2.page.com/    http$1://$http_host/ r;
```

Comment: I am using stretch-backport, the nginx.conf is copy pasted from an old cygwin setup. It's constantly complaining unknow directive `sub_filter`, `proxy_cache`. But I know it works and worked a long time. Changing `sub_filter` to `subs_filter` fixed unknown directive `sub_filter` error, thanks to this thread.

Comment: I would like to add that you can use `sub_filter` (no regex in first parameter) and `subs_filter` with nginx-extras on Ubuntu (better don't mix them?). Note the third parameter in `subs_filter` resp. the switches g = global, i = case-insensitive, o = one, r = regex. Nginx for the win.